# Python: extracting datetime to year, month, and day result in float

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My data has a `datetime` index like this `2016-11-05 23:40:00`.
I want to extract the datetime elements into three new columns of the year, month, and day. I use the following

```
import datetime as dt
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['day'] = df.index.day
```

But the results are in float

```
year    month   day
2016.0  11.0    5.0
```

I want

```
year    month   day
2016    11      5
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `.astype(int)`..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think reason for floats are missing values, so if use pandas 0.24+ is possible use [`Nullable Integer Data Type`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df['year'] = df.index.year.astype('Int64')
df['month'] = df.index.month.astype('Int64')
df['day'] = df.index.day.astype('Int64')
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use `astype`:

```
import datetime as dt
df['year'] = df.index.year.astype(int)
df['month'] = df.index.month.astype(int)
df['day'] = df.index.day.astype(int)
```

If there are Nan's then use errors parameter:

```
df['year'] = df.index.year.astype(int, errors='ignore')
```

This will return nans for the columns with null index

Comment: This will fail if you have `nan`s in the data, so make sure you clean it first.

Comment: But can indexes be `nan`s?

Comment: This returns ```ValueError: Cannot convert NA to integer```. How can be a NaN in index?

Comment: @Darina Apparently indexes can have null values.

Comment: @MohitMotwani With errors parameter, ```astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'```

Comment: That's weird. Did you use it exactly as mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @MohitMotwani. yes, copy-paste

Comment: @MohitMotwani slightly off-topic but yeah, turns out you can even do `df.index = [np.nan]*len(df)`

Answer (score 3):

convert it on int

```
import datetime as dt
df['year'] = int(df.index.year)
df['month'] = int(df.index.month)
df['day'] = int(df.index.day)
```

Comment: I tried it and returned ```TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Float64Index'```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you have a lot of columns, easiest may well be after all the code for constructing data-frame:

```
df = df.astype(int)
```